# Any reason for rootVC to be nill in the following code

Tags: ios

I am doing a login View that is working fine, but I decided to check all VC hierarchy and I found out that the root is nil even after I init it like this:

```
       if([self isLogged] == TRUE) {
            identifier=@"ipadContainer";
        } else {
            identifier=@"iPadloginVC";

        }
        UIStoryboard *storyboardobj=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *screen = [storyboardobj instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
        UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:screen];
        [self.window setRootViewController:navCon];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
```

So after the app is loaded, i do a NSLog in viewDidLod of the iPadloginVC,

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController);
```

the NSLog points that my rootVC is null, and there is one object in the VC hierarchy  and it is the iPadloginVC.

Am I wrong or the NavController should be the root here and not null pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
 UINavigationController *nvc = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
 // get view controller that you want
```